# Paperclip file path using 3 digits for user id

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, paperclip

I am trying to use an image tag in a rails 3 app to show an avatar uploaded by paperclip. My problem is that the path of the file I am trying to link to is structured as so

```
/system/model_name/photos/000/000/model_id/image_size/file_name.jpg
```

The model id however, is always 3 digits. So if the user uploads an avatar and the users id is the #1, the path would look like

```
/system/users/photos/000/000/001/thumb/file_name.jpg
```

so when I link with an image tag like so

```
<%= image_tag "/system/users/photos/000/000/#{@user.id}/medium/#{@user.image_file_name.to_s}" %>
```

I actually get

```
<img src="/system/users/photos/000/000/1/medium/file_name.jpg">
```

If the user id doesn't have three digits should I make the id 3 digits by adding some zeros with ruby? And if so, then how? Am I going about this the wrong way and should just store the paperclip upload path in the db, and if so how? I can't change the upload path of paperclip as the application is in production and would probably make the already uploaded avatars wonky, or at least more difficult to link to.

Comment: I suggest that you use the users actual id as the directory name. Your current solution only allows for 999 users to be placed on the system. While it may never come to having that number of users, it is still more robust.

Comment: This is what I ended up going with. The 999 users thing may never happen, but this seemed like the correct way. I just changed the directory the images were currently stored in.

Answer (score 0):

```
@user.id.length = 1 ? 00#{@user.id} : @user.id.length = 2 ? 0#{@user.id} : @user.id.length = 3 ? #{@user.id}
```

Comment: To make your answer more useful, please add some explanation of what changes you're making and how those changes address the OP's question.